# Data not store in List variable while use stream builder

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

when I used Firestore query data stored in list variable but when I try to use this data outside the query it won't work. Please help me where I'm making mistake.

```
 List<ContactsModelClass> _groupContactList1 ; //declare list variable 
                  _groupCollection
                      .doc(widget.groupId)
                      .collection("groupContactList")
                      .get()
                      .then((docs) {
                    showLog('--->>>>>>${docs.docs.length}');
                    _groupContactList1 = List<ContactsModelClass>.generate(
                      docs.docs.length,
                      (index) => ContactsModelClass.fromJson(
                        docs.docs[index].data(),
                      ),
                    );  //Store data in list variable
                    print("init groupList:[${_groupContactList1.length}]"); //get data 
                  });                   
                  print(
                      "groupContactList list data:[${_groupContactList1.length}]"); // can not access data which store above in code. why?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `then` callback is called later, where you set your `_groupContactList1` . But you print `_groupContactList1.lenght` now, which is not set yet.

Use await instead, try solution below:

```
var docs = await _groupCollection.doc(widget.groupId).collection("groupContactList").get();
showLog('--->>>>>>${docs.docs.length}');
_groupContactList1 = List<ContactsModelClass>.generate(
 docs.docs.length,
 (index) => ContactsModelClass.fromJson(docs.docs[index].data()),
);
print("groupContactList list data:[${_groupContactList1.length}]");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `await` keyword for the fetching of docs from the Firestore. Once Firestore fetches the data then display or use the list.